# Use ReSharper to Change an indexer to Getter/Setter methods

Tags: c#, resharper

Using ReSharper, is there a way to change this code:

```
TValue this[TIndex index]
{
    get // optional
    {
        // getter code
    }
    set // optional
    {
        // setter code
    }
}
```

To this code:

```
TValue GetStuff(TIndex index)
{
    // getter code
}

void SetStuff(TIndex index, TValue value)
{
    // setter code
}
```

And, of course, automatically update usage of the code.

I don't need the inverse operation right now but it can be interesting to know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.

With your pointer on the `this` in the method signature, go to the menu in *Resharper* -> *Refactor* -> *Convert* -> *Indexer To Method...*

The reverse is also possible, but you'll have to do it for both the `GetStuff` and `SetStuff` methods and select the corresponding *Method to Indexer* option.